# Closing up Solspace Freeform form?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I tried to find from Solspace docs, how to close a form that is used as survey for my site users. Didnt find any info according to that. So how I can close the form without losing the data stored?
Is the only way to comment out the form from template and write a notice in place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are placing the form into the page.  Are you simply inserting it into the template? Is it inserted along with an entry?  The logic of how the form gets "closed" is likely something you would want to handle with native EE logic/functionality rather than something specific to Freeform.  Perhaps expiring the entry that makes up the page within which the form is inserted, or changing the text of that page and removing the form on the basis of a date having passed - something like that - since forms themselves, I don't believe, have any such functionality.

Comment: Yep. Im using simply Freeform:Form-tags, so therefore there is nothing to do as far as I see it. So I just commented the form itself out and replaced "closed" text for users.

Comment: That's basically it, yes, though you could automate it somewhat if needed by using simple date conditionals to determine if the current time is past a fixed date you specify and remove the form and change the messaging accordingly.